# Retrieving address of a function from ExE or Bin file

Tags: windows, function, disassembly

Which program can you recommend for me if I want to retrieve dissasembled code and absolute addresses of functions placed in exe file or binary file ??

Comment: What OS ? E.g. for *nix or even cygwin under Windows use od, for Mac OS X use otool, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Unix/Linux: use '[nm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nm_(Unix))' or '[objdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump)'.
For Windows use '[dumpbin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429)'

**Edit:** As ***oneat*** pointed out he did not have Visual C++, it might be better to download [OpenWatcom C++](http://www.openwatcom.org), which has the equivalent functionality called 'wdump.exe' bundled with it. [Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Analysis_Tools) is another site that contains the tools and what they do on wikibooks.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Something without visual c++, please.

Comment: I don't have this utility in windows XP!
It needs Visual C++ installed!

Comment: @oneat: Please see my edited answer...you should check out the open source Watcom C++ compiler which will have wdump installed.